# Reproducing glibc error detected in linux

Tags: c

What are the possible situations that can cause glibc error detected double free corruption error while executing a C program in Linux(netbsd) that writes data to an SD card.

The program takes care of properly checking file pointers before calling fclose() and assigns unused pointers to null.

Forcibly removing the SD card during a write operation is not causing any errors.

Are there any other scenarios that could cause this error?

Comment: Can you show a small ([minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) example program that exhibits the behaviour?

Comment: The entire code is huge and the part of the code that deals with writing files is causing the issue, I haven't been able to reproduce this but the bug exists.

Comment: Will umounting the SD card during a write operation cause any errors?